# I am having issue in checking whether a username exists or not in my angular 6 application via api

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

This is my reactive form validation code

```
userName: new FormControl('',[Validators.required,Validators.maxLength(50),this.checkIfUsernameExists.bind(this)])
```

});

And this is my validation function written in the same file

```
checkIfUsernameExists(control){
var that = this;
return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        that.dashdata.checkUsernameExists(control.value).subscribe(ret=>{
        if(ret!="0"){ 
            resolve({'emailvalid': true});
        }else{
            resolve(null);
        }`enter code here`
        });
    }, 1000);        
});
}
```

And the html code is like

```
              <input type="text" id="username-input"  class="form-control" placeholder="Enter username"  autocomplete="email" formControlName="userName" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && formfields.userName.errors }">
              <span class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="formfields.userName.errors.emailvalid">This username already exists</span>
              <span class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="formfields.userName.errors.required">Please enter a username</span>
```

Comment: For starters, you need to bind it as an async validator when you create the `FormControl` Take a look at the [API doc](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create async validator to check and apply validation on FormControl field. below is dummy code which can help you to develop your own

create another file user.validator.ts

```
export class ValidateUsername {
  static createValidator(service: userService) {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
      if (!control.valueChanges || control.pristine) {
        return of(null);
      } else {
        return control.valueChanges.pipe(
          debounceTime(300),
          distinctUntilChanged(),
          take(1),
          switchMapTo(service.checkUsernameExists(control.value)),
          tap(() => control.markAsTouched()),
          map((data) => (data.exist ? { userExist: true } : null))
        );
      }
    };
  }
}
```

and use in the reactive form in such a way

```
userName: [
                '',
                [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)],
                ValidateUsername.createValidator(this.userService)
            ],
```

and in HTML

```
<div *ngIf="username.touched && username.errors">
    <span *ngIf="formName.controls['userName']?.errors?.required">Please enter email address.</span>
    <span *ngIf="formName.controls['userName']?.errors?.pattern">Maximum
                                    {{formName.controls['userName']?.errors?.maxlength.requiredLength}} characters are
                                    allowed.</span>
    <span *ngIf="inviteForm.controls['userName']?.errors?.userExist">User already exists. </span>
    </div>
<div *ngIf="user.status === 'PENDING'">
    <span class="text-info">Checking...</span>
</div>
```